# Annoying Snow Effect from GFX Card

Tags: google-chrome, graphics-card

I turned my PC on this morning, to see an annoying snow type effect, the problem seems to only display on my Central monitor, and on Google Chrome, I was thinking it may be due to a Chrome update, as one was pending here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]
<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>

I have no Idea why it is doing this, but it is hard to work with it. Has anyone had this problem, and able to help me fix it?

**Edit** : Also to explain it on my Central Monitor, might be because Chrome shows Toast Notifications, but not too sure, I will uninstall Chrome to test.

Comment: It seems to be doing it on Firefox too, and Photoshop says it has detected a problem with the Graphics Driver, so it's not just a Chrome problem

Comment: To me, it looks like the graphics card is overheating, or on its way out. What are your system specs ?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the drivers? Have you ran any diagnostics provided by the manufacturer? Provide some more details about your system so someone might be able to guide you.

Comment: @Lawrence - http://valid.canardpc.com/4a7qxa

Comment: @CharlieRB - I am uninstalling all NVidia and Intel Graphics Drives, and will restart PC to see if that fixes it

Comment: Uninstall Intel Drivers, restarted PC, Middle monitor didn't display anything, but I didn't have the problem, so reinstalled Intel drivers and it started doing it again :/, starting to think my on-board GFX is dying :(

Comment: It fixed it's self, don't know how, don't care to know how, but it's fine now, I'm happy :)

Comment: hmm started again, added new screenshot to main post

Comment: just FYI, took my PC to PCWorld for testing, turns out the onboard gfx card died :/, So I have now bought a replacement MOBO and CPU